# What are the (possible) fundamental reasons for all zeros of zeta function to be on the critical line?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

What are the (possible) fundamental reasons for all zeros of zeta function to be on the critical line ?

Are there particular mechanism to make this happen ?

Because of Levinson and Corney's work, we know over 2/5 of all zeros are on critical line. But do we have any fundamental reasons why those zeros are on critical line ?

Do we have even have reason why first three zeros are on critical line ?

Comment: "what are the possible reasons for all zeros of the zeta function to be on the critical line?".As far as I know ,it is not yet known/proven if all the zeros of the riemann zeta function lie on the critical line.

Comment: One possible "reason" could be related to the PNT: the primes distribution behaves in the "most random way" and one might say that for some "natural" reason we expect such a randomness, but to be honest the truth of Riemann Hypothesis is far from granted, even if some results point in this direction. In fact, different analytic number theorists suggest RH might be false in analogy with what happened with other "unexpected" phenomena, like the infinite oscillation in sign of $\pi(x)-{\rm li(x)}$, take a look for example at this work of Ivic: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0311162v1.pdf